# convert alphabets to coresponding numbers

Tags: javascript

i have to convert alphabets to corresponding numbers like i have a data like "DRSG004556722000TU77" and the index for A is 10, B is 11, C is 12 and so on up to Z is 35.

any helping tips??

here is the javascript which return me ascii code but i want to get the above indecies for respective alphabet

```
var string = DRSG004556722000TU77;
    function getColumnName(string) {
    return ((string.length - 1) * 26) + (string.charCodeAt(string.length - 1) - 64);
    }
    document.write( getColumnName(string) );
```

Comment: @Downvoter, could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
var output = [], code, str = 'DRSG004556722000TU77',i;
for(i in str){
 code = str.charCodeAt(i);
 if(code <= 90 && code >= 65){
 // Add conditions " && code <= 122 && code >= 97" to catch lower case letters
   output.push([i,code]);
 }
}
```

Now ouput contains all letters codes and their corresponding indexes

Comment: Copy / paste this code followed by "console.log(output)" in firebug console to test `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'DRSG004556722000TU77';

function getColumnName(string) {
    var recode = new Array(), i, n = string.length;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        recode.push(filter(string.charCodeAt(i)));
    }
    return recode;
}

function filter(symbol) {
    if ((symbol >= 65) && (symbol <= 90)) {
        return symbol - 55;
    } else if ((symbol >= 48) && (symbol <= 57)) {
        return symbol - 48;
    }
}

document.write(getColumnName(string));
```

Comment: the out put give me commas after each number how to remove them i need the result without commas or sapces in beten digits. infact i am new to jquery

Comment: @Kashif Waheed you can use: `recode = recode + filter(string.charCodeAt(i));` instead of: `recode.push(filter(string.charCodeAt(i)));` also change: `var recode = new Array()` onto: `var recode = ""`